# printing all avalilabe info in observer object Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to print all available information in the observer object,

Suppose I have a event in app/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml:

**Config.xml** :

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_modulename_checkout_cart_product_add_after_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>onAddToCart</method>
                    </namespace_modulename_checkout_cart_product_add_after_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

This event will call the function onAddToCart in Observer.php:
This event successfully calls the funtion.
**Observer.php:**

```
public function onAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $name = $product->getName();
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        Mage::log(
            "{$name} ({$sku}) updated",
            null,
            'product-updates.log'
        );
    }
```

What I wanna do in onAddToCart function is something like this:

```
public function onAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $test4 = var_dump($observer->getDataObject()->getData());
        Mage::log(
            "{$test4}",
            null,
            'product-updates.log'
        );
    }
```

**Problem:**
When I do

```
$test4 = var_dump($observer->getDataObject()->getData());
            Mage::log(
                "{$test4}",
                null,
                'product-updates.log'
            );
```

I get this error in system.log file:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Observer.php on line 62
```

And it doesn't print anything using var_dump function,
what I want is that all info available in the observer object gets printed automatically, like an array gets printed using print_r, but I have tried var_dump as well as print_r with no success on $observer object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: With print_r instead of var_dump,

```
$test4 = print_r($observer->getDataObject()->getData(), true);
Mage::log(
    "{$test4}",
    null,
    'product-updates.log'
);
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `$test4 = print_r($observer->getDataObject()->getData(), true);`

Comment: already tried print_r, doesn't work, tried once again on your request, didn't work, the payment process doesn't get executed due to this..

Comment: You missed the the second param `true`

Comment: Hi Simon, No I didn't miss it. I used true, it doesn't work.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your other code. Please add the full code for print_r. That is the way to go.

Comment: added the print_r code

Comment: Did you solve it?